# jquery menu in a silverlight web application

Tags: jquery, silverlight

I'm trying to implement a jquery menu in a silverlight web application.
Since I'm just a newbie, could anybody give me a step by step guide on how to do this?

I'd be very thankful for any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use jQuery or javascript code inside a Silverlight application. You can host your Silverlight application in a web page that has a jQuery menu. Your Silverlight application can interact with javascript in the page that is hosted. You can define entry points in your Silverlight application and call them through javascript.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, is there a site where i can find simple tutorial on this?

Comment: or do you think it is better to use jquery menu with asp.net mvc?

Comment: I would say either use ASP.Net MVC + jQuery Menu or use a Silverlight menu (some third party controls are available). It doesn't make much sense to combine a jQuery menu with silverlight.